# Jenkins Powershell write to console

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins job that calls a powershell file.  When I use it from a freestyle project it shows the powershell execution in the console output.  Having switched it to a pipeline job I no longer see the output.

Currently my pipeline looks like this:

```
 pipeline 
 {
    stages
    {
        stage ('Deploy To Dev')
         {
            steps
             {
                powershell '"%WORKSPACE%\\SpearsLoad\\Scripts\\CIDeployToDev.Ps1"'
             }
        }
    }
}
```

but I get no logging of the powershell steps.

Following the documentation I tried changing the stage to:

```
pipeline 
{
    stages
    {
        stage ('Deploy To Dev')
            {
            steps
            {
                node('Deploy the SSIS load')
                {
                    //Deploy the SSIS load
                    def msg = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '"%WORKSPACE%\\SpearsLoad\\Scripts\\CIDeployToDev.Ps1"')
                    println msg
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but that gives:

> Expected a step @ line 123, column 6. def msg =
>   powershell(returnStdout: true, script:
>   '"%WORKSPACE%\SpearsLoad\Scripts\CIDeployToDev.Ps1"')

I feel like I am missing something quite fundamental. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap your pipeline execution into `script` section, because you're trying to use scripted syntax in [declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script):

```
script {
    //Deploy the SSIS load
    def msg = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '"%WORKSPACE%\\SpearsLoad\\Scripts\\CIDeployToDev.Ps1"')
    println msg
}
```

Comment: Thanks I thought it might be a fundamental misunderstanding cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who comes here looking for answers, I need to point out that there were actually 3 separate problems with the code:

1. The lack of a script section as per the accepted answer.
2. The powershell was not actually running due to not calling it correctly
3. The powershell was not running due to spaces in the %WORKSPACE% variable

in the end, I went with:

```
script {
    def msg = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: " & './SpearsLoad\\Scripts\\CIDeployToDev.Ps1'")
    println msg
}
```

which actually works!

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
Write-Host "My message"
```

in powershell. This will show up in the log.